# how to apply shadow effects for right border in alternative td's in a table

Tags: html, styles, shadow, css

how to set a right shadow border for alternative tds in a table .
    I am trying with the below code. In this shadow effects works.but the shadow effects will cut in each tds join.Anyone can help me?
    My table is

```
<table class="myTable" style="padding: 2em;width: 100%;">
 <tr><th>subject</th>
     <th>name</th>   
     <th>mark1</th>
     <th>mark2</th>
     <th>total</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
     <td>english</td>
     <td>abc</td>
     <td>10</td>
     <td>23</td>
     <td>33</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
     <td>latin</td>
     <td>abc</td>
     <td>10</td>
     <td>23</td>
     <td>33</td>
 </tr>
 ........
</table>
```

Iam using this code for shadow effect

```
table.myTable td:nth-child(even)
{
       box-shadow: 16px 3px 10px -7px #888, -10px 0px 20px -7px #888;
}
```

Comment: your code seems to work fine

Answer (score 0):

```
    <table class="myTable" style="padding: 2em;width: 100%;">
 <tr><th>subject</th>
     <th>name</th>   
     <th>mark1</th>
     <th>mark2</th>
     <th>total</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
     <td style="box-shadow:16px 3px 10px">english</td>
     <td>abc</td>
     <td>10</td>
     <td>23</td>
     <td>33</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
     <td>latin</td>
     <td>abc</td>
     <td>10</td>
     <td>23</td>
     <td>33</td>
 </tr>
 ........
</table>
```

Aply to td a style

Comment: Inline styles are really horrible.

Answer (score 0):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hH6Rv/)

`<tr>`-specifies the row
`<td>`-specifies the column

in the demo the columns that are even are with shadows

css:

```
table.myTable td:nth-child(even)
{
       box-shadow: 16px 3px 10px -7px #888, -10px 0px 20px -7px #888;
}
.center{text-align:center;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could just separate the cells with border-collapse and put on border-spacing.

example: http://codepen.io/pen/srwCi